# PubSub.js: Subscribe to all events

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe

For debugging and documentation, I want to log the event-name of all PubSub-events in the console. After reading https://sahadar.github.io/pubsub/#subscribe_wildcard I thought I could simply do this:

```
PubSub.subscribe('*', function(e) {
   console.log('pubsub-event: "'+e+'"');
});
```

but it isn't called. Any idea?

Comment: read the previous section ... `"*" goes only one namespace deeper` so `'*'` would only (I assume) subscribe to `hello` but not `hello/world` ?

Comment: the event I'm trying it on is named "product-detail-save-basket-as-list', so no namespace-hierarchy at all - that's why I expected it to work

Comment: ok, wasn't clear from your question ... it's almost as if you can't have `*` on the "root" level (none of the examples do and the code isn't the easiest to read)

Comment: sadly, that seems to be the case. Changing all events is not an option, as our customer is already working with parts of our work :-(